# MS SQL Query failed in PHP but not in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: php, sql

I execute this query with php and odbc driver

```
$sql="DECLARE @Auftrag int; 
DECLARE @date_now datetime = getdate(); 
EXEC @Auftrag=EHS.dbo.SP_ANZEIGE 
@Tablet=1, 
@Status=0, 
@KuNr='K015538'; 
SELECT 'generatedID'=@Auftrag;";

$res = odbc_exec($db1_link, $sql) or die(odbc_errormsg()); // returns resource(13)
$firstRow = odbc_fetch_array($res); // dies error
```

If i do odbc_fetch_array the error "No tuples available at this result index" is thrown.

If I run the exact same query in Management Studio everything works fine. It shows me the computed generatedID. What is the difference?

greets Alex

Comment: Show us, how you do run this query in php

Comment: Try to prefix the query with: `set nocount on`.  That prevents SQL Server from sending rowcount updates, which UNIX clients sometimes mistake for actual rowsets.

Comment: WOW ... set nocount on really did it. I don't know exactly why but I'm really happy :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to prefix the query with:

```
set nocount on
```

That prevents SQL Server from sending rowcount updates, which UNIX clients sometimes mistake for actual rowsets

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. In my case I was executing like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$resultSet = odbc_exec($sqllink, $sql);

while ($data = odbc_fetch_array($resultSet)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table2";
    $resultSet2 = odbc_exec($sqllink, $sql);//failed here
    while ($data2 = odbc_fetch_array($resultSet2)) {

           //something here

    }
}
```

and I changed like this and it worked

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$resultSet = odbc_exec($sqllink, $sql);

// Create an array and store the results

$queryResult = array();

while ($data = odbc_fetch_array($resultSet)) {

    // push the required content into the array

    $queryResult[$data['id']]['name'] = $data[name];
}

foreach($queryResult as $row) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table2";
    $resultSet2 = odbc_exec($sqllink, $sql);
    while ($data2 = odbc_fetch_array($resultSet2)) {

        // something here

    }
}
```